# Translations with glMultMatrixf, and when to normalize

Tags: android, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, 3d

So I can understand things better, I'm trying to get away from calling the gl transformation functions (glTranslatef / glRotatef etc.) instead I'm creating my own matrices and using glMultMatrixf().

The matrix I've created for x/y/z rotation seems to work flawlessly, but my translation matrix appears to collapse all the vertices of my meshes into a single axis.

Am I off base in thinking that passing a matrix:

```
    { 1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,x
      0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,y,
      0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,z,
      0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
```

to glMultMatrixf is the same as doing glTranslatef(x,y,z)? (I'm column major. Just to make sure I wasn't all backwards I transposed the above matrix and it still didn't work. Just seemed to flatten everything to a different axis.)

Am I missing a normalize step somewhere? When IS it a good idea to normalize your matrices.

Thanks ahead of time for dropping some knowledge on me folks!

These are my rotation Matrices:
XAxis

```
{ 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
  0.0f, (float) Math.cos(x), (float) -Math.sin(x), 0.0f,
  0.0f, (float) Math.sin(x), (float) Math.cos(x), 0.0f,
  0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
```

YAxis

```
{ (float) Math.cos(y),0.0f,(float) Math.sin(y),0.0f,
   0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f,
  (float) -Math.sin(y),0.0f,(float) Math.cos(y),0.0f,
   0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
```

ZAxis

```
 { (float) Math.cos(z),(float) -Math.sin(z),0,0,
   (float) Math.sin(z),(float) Math.cos(z),0,0,
   0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f,
   0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks transposed to me. The element order should be:

```
   0   4   8   12
   1   5   9   13
   2   6   10  14
   3   7   11  15
```

But you've got x in element 3, it should be element 12 (same for y and z).

===Edit ===

sorry just noticed you already said you transposed it. But x should definitely be in element 12, just to confirm it for you. I don't think you'd have to do anything extra to the matrix to get it to work.

Comment: Good job sticking to your guns, when I said I transposed it I apparently transposed it in a completely crazy way. (I had put x,y,z in indices 1,2 and 3 :X)

Comment: Would you mind telling me if my rotation matrices are jacked too? I mean.. They seem to work "visibly", but I'd like to verify with someone smarter than me (you). I'll edit the original post.

Comment: @MrLeap: You should just be able to copy the formulas directly from glRotate man page: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glRotate.xml

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a much more terse way to do it than the way i'm doing it. Thanks for all your help tim! If I had more reputation I'd vote you up too :P